# Manter option selecionado carregado dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Preciso manter a option escolhida no combobox depois da pagina ser submetida,
eu tenho uma função que faz isso, mas apenas para combobox estaticas, para as combobox dinamicas ele não funciona. já estou a horas a pesquisar e não encontro nada.

```js
function cursos() {

  $.getJSON('https://localhost/uan/curso/pesquisaPor/', {}).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(id, valor) {

      $("#curso").append('<option value="' + valor.id + '">' + valor.nome + '</option>');
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Curso<span class="required">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select class="span6 m-wrap" id="curso" name="curso">
      <option value="">Selecciona um curso</option>
    </select>


  </div>
</div>
```

A função cursos retorna todos os cursos que estão na base de dados e preenche o select, dinamicamente, acontece que sempre que envio o formulario eu queria que ele marca-se o option selecionado..

Comment: O que você tentou? Adicione o código à pergunta.

Comment: E o código que gera o `data` para sua função `JavaScript`? É lá que você precisa verificar qual `option` da `select` foi enviada e retornar.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que uma maneira fácil de se resolver isso, é enviando o valor da `select` para a página que você precisa.

Vamos supor que você receba a `select` desse modo:

```
$_POST["lista"];
```

Você pode enviar esta variável para a página que deseja, via `POST` ou via `GET`.

No momento em que estiver gerando os `<option>`, você precisa verificar se existe um `$_POST["lista"]`, se sim, utilize ele para marcar a `option` na sua `select`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
$lista = array(
  "um" => 1,
  "dois" => 2,
  "tres" => 3,
  "quatro" => 4
);

// Aqui você verifica se a variável $_POST["lista"]
// e não é nula
$selecionado = "tres";
?>

<select name="opcoes">

<?php
foreach($lista as $chave => $valor) {
    if($selecionado == $chave) {
      echo "<option value=".$chave." selected>".$valor."</option>";
    } else {
      echo "<option value=".$chave.">".$valor."</option>";
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: o meu caso é um pouco diferente desse de uma olhada como esta o codigo function cursos() {

    $.getJSON('https://localhost/uan/curso/pesquisaPor/', {
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (id, valor) {

            $("#curso").append('<option value="' + valor.id + '">' + valor.nome + '</option>');
        });
    });
}

Comment: @Sam, quanto mais código você adicionar a sua pergunta, melhor, adicione esse código na sua pergunta por favor e também adicione o que julgar necessário.

Comment: aqui tenho o select que preenche automaticamente <select class="span6 m-wrap" id="curso" name="curso">
                                    <option value="">Selecciona um curso</option>
                                </select>

Comment: @Sam, você precisa então fazer essa verificação com `JavaScript` e não `PHP`, já que é o `JavaScript` o responsável por gerar a lista. Você pode enviar o valor da `option` selecinada no seu `data`: `$.each(data...`

Comment: pode dar um exemplo pra servir como base?

Comment: @Sam, adicione à sua resposta, o código do seu `JavaScript` e também o código que gera o retorno para sua chamada Ajax, por favor

Comment: @Sam, sem conhecer um pouco do seu código, fica muito difícil ajudar.

Comment: alterei a pergunta pode ver o codigo

Answer (score 1):

Junta mais uma propriedade no JSON que retornas do servidor. Para além de `id` e `nome` podias juntar `selected`, como booleano.

Depois no JavaScript ficaria:

```
$.each(data, function(id, valor) {
      var selected = valor.selected ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
      $("#curso").append('<option ' + selected + ' value="' + valor.id + '">' + valor.nome + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passa um parâmetro  pela URL. E recupera via get e verifica no JavaScript se existe algum option do select igual ao valor recuperado pelo get.